# Makefile target running parallel targets and waiting for them to complete before doing more stuff

Tags: multithreading, makefile, threadpool, gnu-make

I am trying to have a "parent target" waiting for "parallel children targets" to complete before doing something in the "body" of the "parent target".

In the following example the message `@echo "Print this only after *ALL* the previous PARALLEL tasks are done!"` should be printed only **after** all the targets `foo-task1`, `foo-task2` and `foo-task3` have completed.

**If I remove the ampersand (`&`)** at the end of those "children targets" **then they become serial**, but that's not the expected behavior. They should behave similar to a "thread pool" or "process pool". I don't know in advance which of those targets will complete last, so I can not remove the ampersand (`&`) from the bottleneck target.

Those targets represent HTTP calls to a remote REST API that could require variable amounts of time to complete. I would like to wait for these "parallel REST calls" to see if they succeeded before printing the final message in `foo-parallel`.

These "parallel targets" are returning stdout/stderr so I wish the parent target could wait for them and fail in case there are some errors.

How could I do this?

```
foo-task1:
    @bash -c 'sleep 1 && echo "task1" &'

foo-task2:
    @bash -c 'sleep 1 && echo "task2" &'

foo-task3:
    @bash -c 'sleep 2 && echo "task3" &'

foo-parallel: foo-task3 foo-task2 foo-task1
    @echo "Print this only after *ALL* the previous PARALLEL tasks are done!"
```

The command `make` version:

```
$ make --version
GNU Make 4.1
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

**edit:**

This slightly different target definition (I changed the `sleep` times just to make sure the messages print in the delayed order rather than the order in the code):

```
foo-parallel:
    @bash -c 'sleep 5 && echo "task1" & \
                        sleep 1 && echo "task2" & \
                        sleep 2 && echo "task3" & \
                        wait; \
                        echo "done here!"'
```

prints:

```
$ make foo-parallel 
task2
task3
task1
done here!
```

but I need to put the logic of all those `task1`, `task2` and `task3` inside the same target. I would like to split those tasks into different targets.

Comment: Why don't you use the `-j` option? I think this is the best method in `make` for parallelization (see https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Parallel).

Comment: Did not know about this J option. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome! I created a detailed answer too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this, without using make's `-j` option.  By default make builds one target, waits for it to complete, then builds the next one.  Only with `-j` will it support multiple targets running at the same time.

```
foo-parallel: foo-task3 foo-task2 foo-task1
        @echo "Print this only after *ALL* the previous PARALLEL tasks are done!"

foo-task1:
        @sleep 1 && echo "task1"

foo-task2:
        @sleep 1 && echo "task2"

foo-task3:
        @sleep 2 && echo "task3"
```

Then run: `make -j`  Or if you want to restrict the number of parallel builds, use `make -j2` or however many you want.

If you REALLY want to avoid typing the `-j` you can use recursive make:

```
foo-parallel:
        @$(MAKE) -j foo-task1 foo-task2 foo-task3
        @echo "Print this only after *ALL* the previous PARALLEL tasks are done!"

foo-task1:
        @sleep 1 && echo "task1"

foo-task2:
        @sleep 1 && echo "task2"

foo-task3:
        @sleep 2 && echo "task3"
```

However this might cause odd warnings if someone does invoke `make -j`.  Generally I think it's better to leave it up to the person invoking `make` as to how much parallelism they want, for their particular system.

Comment: Thanks! What if there is a `all` target that defined as `all: foo-first-serial foo-3-parallel-targets foo-last-serial`, if I invoke it as `make -j3 all` is it going to respect the serial chain `foo-first-serial` then 3 parallel targets, then `foo-last-serial`?

Comment: Ok, I've tried out the 2nd option you suggested from the command line like `make all` and it works as expected (i.e. `foo-first-serial` then 3 parallel targets, then `foo-last-serial`), but I can see the odd warning when calling it like `make -j2 aaa`, so I guess this is it, there is no cleaner way to enforce some sort of flow like serial>parallel>serial?

Comment: You'll have to specify the prerequisites that you want specifically: so create `foo-first-serial: | foo-3-parallel` to ensure that ordering, and `foo-3-parallel: | foo-last-serial` to ensure that ordering.  Here I'm using order-only prerequisites but you could just use normal ones instead if that works better.  All makefiles should always explicitly declare their dependency graph; to not do so leads to heartache and pain.

Comment: It's a bad idea to rely on the order in which targets appear in the prerequisite lists to enforce order of build.  If you need to enforce things building in a certain order, you should use target/prerequisite statements to tell make about it.

Comment: Uhm to enforce the execution of: `foo-first-serial`, then 3 parallel targets `foo-3-parallel`, then a last serial target `foo-last-serial` I had to define the order-only prerequisites (the pipe thing `|`) in a different way, this: `foo-3-parallel: | foo-first-serial` and `foo-last-serial: | foo-3-parallel`. Then from the command line I had to call it this way: `time make foo-last` (the `time` is to measure the required time to check if the parallel thing is being parallel). Here some quite obscure explanation of pipes: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types

Comment: Oops got it backwards.  But yes, in make you ALWAYS specify the final target you want to be built on the command line, not the first one.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use the `-j` option:

```
foo-task1:
    @sleep 1
    @echo "task1"

foo-task2:
    @sleep 1
    @echo "task2"

foo-task3:
    @sleep 2
    @echo "task3"

foo-parallel: foo-task3 foo-task2 foo-task1
    @echo "Print this only after *ALL* the previous PARALLEL tasks are done!"
```

And run `make -j3 foo-parallel` - the `make` will run parallel with correct dependency. See more [Parallel Execution](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Parallel) section:

> GNU make knows how to execute several recipes at once. Normally, make
>   will execute only one recipe at a time, waiting for it to finish
>   before executing the next. However, the ‘-j’ or ‘--jobs’ option tells
>   make to execute many recipes simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks! What if there is a `all` target that defined as `all: foo-first-serial foo-3-parallel-targets foo-last-serial`, if I invoke it as `make -j3 all` is it going to respect the serial chain `foo-first-serial` then 3 parallel targets, then `foo-last-serial`?

Comment: @TPPZ: I see MadScientist answered you below his answer.